# Generating a Global Variable counter from tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, global-variables

I am using a single UITableview segueing to one UIViewController.
There is a only a slight change in material on the UIViewController depending on what UITableview row is selected.

I have done it before segueing to multiple UIViewControllers because there were many things different between the UIViewControllers such as layouts etc. But as its only one simple difference between view controllers I want to use a global counter variable. 
I want to use set the value of a counter to the value of the row selected and store that value globally.

I declare the counter:

```
var counter: Int?
```

Then when a row is selected I set the counter value to that row and perform a segue:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    counter = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)    
}
```

In the viewController I segued to the `counter` has a value of `'nil'`.
Why is this? And how can I fix it.
I know this is not the best practice but it is what I want to try and do in this case.

Comment: How you read `counter` value? Perhaps from wrong container.

Comment: In the viewDidLoad function of the view controller am print the counter value to make sure it works. However it is returning nil. its like the 'counter = indexPath.row' is not updating the global value of 'var counter: Int?'

Answer (score 0):

The value of `counter` variable become `nil` and it's expected. Because when you going to segue a new controller, you did not assign the value of counter variable. You just update your existing controller's counter variable with `tableView` `didSelect` method. There are couple of solutions for this problem. Here I have shared the most convenient one.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var counter: Int?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        counter = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "dayx", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewController {
            destinationVC.counter = counter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. I had a play around with it there but the code you posted does not work. Its produces there error `use of unresolved identifier 'counter'` in the view controller I segue to. I moved the 'var counter: Int?' above the 'class ViewController' but that didn't work either.

Comment: Here counter variable is belong to that controller which you are going to segue (push or modal). In the example I try to show that I am going to push a controller named as ViewController which has counter variable. In your case if will be different e.g. if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourController

Comment: I did have a play around using `if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? MyController`  but the when it states that `MyController` has no member `counter` because counter. I think this is because `counter` is only declared in the tableViewController.swift file and not MyController.swift?